# Cloned Jupyter Notebook in VS Code generating OSError: [WinError 123] on os.getcwd() statement

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have a Github Jupyter notebook repository that I have cloned in VS Code.  The code is failing on the `os.getcwd()` line. I cannot figure out why this is. The error message is as follows:

```
Failed to start the Kernel. 
OSError:  [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '"c:'. 
View Jupyter log for further details.
```

I checked my packages via: "conda list" and I can confirm that I have the following packages installed related to Jupyter:

```
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py36_7
jupyter_client            7.1.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jupyter_console           6.4.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jupyter_core              4.8.1            py36haa95532_0
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2                      py_0
jupyterlab_widgets        1.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
```

I can also confirm if that if I go into VS Code settings that Jupyter.Notebook File root is set to `${fileDirname}`.

The code is below:

```
import io, time, json
import pandas as pd
import urllib#, urllib2
import re
import os
from os.path import join
import numpy as np
import ftplib
from ftplib import FTP
import timeit
import sys
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

current_working_directory = os.getcwd()
print(current_working_directory)
```

Comment: What happens if you remove all the imports and leave just the line `current_working_directory = os.getcwd()`?

Comment: Deleting the import statements generates the same error. The Jupyter logs note the following: OSError: File 'c:\\Users\\<username>\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\kernel-v2-17312XbC14HS1ao7Z.json' does not exist in any of the search paths: ['.', 'C:\\Users\\<username>\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime'].  And I can confirm that that kernel does not exisit in the noted file path.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the response](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/13547#issuecomment-1562310168) by developer on github.

- Download the following file and extract it
- Go into VS Code insiders
- Go into the command palette and select the command Install from VSIX
- and select this VSIX download
- Reload VS Code and test again, it should work

[ms-toolsai-jupyter-insiders.vsix (1).zip](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/files/11561468/ms-toolsai-jupyter-insiders.vsix.1.zip)

And this fix will be applied to pre-release and stable versions in the near future.